# Parse c# get id of a pointer

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

I'm trying to get the id of a pointer in a class, the problem is I don't know how exactly do that, I was trying this:

```
var obj = new ParseObject ("Class");
var resultsitemsfilt = await ParseObject.GetQuery("Class").WhereEqualTo ("classId", class.ObjectId.ToString()).FindAsync ();
foreach (var res in resultsitemsfilt) 
{
    obj=res["pointer_class"];
}
ObjectId = obj.ObjectId.ToString ();
```

But it doesn't work, tells me that there is a problem converting an object to ParseObject, but I don't know how to save the object as an object and then get the id.

Comment: Why are you iterating through all of the items if you just want the last one?  Why not just use `resultsitemsfilt.LastOrDefault()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
var obj = new ParseObject ("Class");
var resultsitemsfilt = await ParseObject.GetQuery("Class").WhereEqualTo ("classId", class.ObjectId.ToString()).FindAsync ();
foreach (var res in resultsitemsfilt) 
{
obj=res.Get<ParseUser>("pointer_class");
}
```

Then you can use it as a normal ParseObject/User as:

```
String ObjectId = obj.ObjectId.ToString ();
```